# ionic cordova platform add android --save

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

cordova.cmd platform add android
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\android\package.json'
{
errno: -4058,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'open',
path: 'D:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\android/package.json'
}

An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

cordova.cmd platform add android exited with exit code 1.

I have done

- ionic cordova platform remove android
- npm install -g cordova@latest
- ionic cordova platform add android --save --verbose

Still I can not get platforms folder to add android nor ios so I can never do a build

I am Lost and have tried about every suggestion I have found to no avail

is there anyone whom can help?